# What is the right approach for resolving save operations with Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I have a classic situation where I want to commit some action only once. For example update some entity in database using Swift Combine. My problem is that I don't really know what is the best approach for doing something only once. How do I unsubscribe when the update is finished?

This is code snippet through the layers that I am currently using:

ViewModel:
    let settingsModel: LocalSettingsModel

```
func saveLocalSettings(){
    let cancelable = settingsUseCase
                         .saveLocalSettings(localSettingsModel: settingsModel)
                         .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
                             print("Completed!!!")

                         }) { _ in
                             print("Result of Save operation!!!")
                         }
}
```

UseCase:

```
func saveLocalSettings(settings: LocalSettingsModel) -> AnyPublisher<LocalSettingsModel, Error> {
    return repository.saveLocalSettings(settings: settings)
}
```

Repository:

```
    guard let realmSettings = LocalSettingsRealmModel(fromModel: settings) else {
            return Fail<LocalSettingsModel, Error>(error: .postconditionError(errorMessage: ""))
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

    return self.localDataSource
        .saveLocalSettings(localSettings: realmSettings)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
        .mapError { (error) -> Error in
             // do error mapping
        }
        .compactMap { settings in
            return (LocalSettingsModel(fromModel: settings))
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Data Source:

```
func saveLocalSettings(localSettings: LocalSettingsRealmModel) -> AnyPublisher<LocalSettingsRealmModel, LocalDataSourceError> {
    do {
        return Just(try saveSettings(localSettings: localSettings))
            .mapError({ (Never) -> LocalDataSourceError in})
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // return some error
    }
}

func saveSettings(localSettings: LocalSettingsRealmModel) throws -> LocalSettingsRealmModel
{
    let realm = try Realm()

    try realm.write {
        realm.add(localSettings, update: .modified)
    }

    return localSettings
}
```

I would really appreciate some pointers in the direction of what is a good practice when we are not expecting continuous stream of information in reactive world like in case of functions whose purpose is to execute single action. Do I really need to use Just() like in this example or is there a way do deal with this kind of situations from subscriber side.

Answer (score 0):

You want something that will convert a Publisher into a single value and then terminate, and the sequence operators in Combine are what you want to use for that kind of thing.

Combine is set up to deal with one OR many values. So you, as the consumer, need to give it some way to constrain the potentially many values into a single value, if you want to use an `assign` subscriber to set a value (or `sink` subscriber to invoke a closure where you do your save, in your case).

The sequence operators in Combine is where I'd think to look, but I can't really describe *which* one without knowing how many values and how you'd choose which one to apply. The two "easy" options are either [`first`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-first) or [`last`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-last), but there's a variety of sequence operators that let you construct more complicated choices (including [`firstWhere`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-firstwhere) and [`lastWhere`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-lastwhere) which let you determine based on your own closure, which can be darned handy.

The embedded links are all to the online/free-version of [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) (disclosure: which I wrote) - and while I don't have any explicit examples about the sequence operators, I did flesh out the reference details for them in the book quite a bit.

Unless you're explicitly working from a publisher, you may find it easier to use a Promise library - depending on what's triggering your save. I don't know the Realm end of this to know what their API focuses on, and if you've made the publisher that's generating the data, or if that's coming from their API - and hence your desire to using Combine to solve this.

Comment: Use case is save operation, so I would like to send save request and receive some save response, I do not expect to have a stream of values, only one, status like response. In your opinion is there an up side of using RX opposed to conventional save command and if there is what is it?

Comment: for a single value response, using RX seems over-tooled - more than you need. RX is heavily oriented towards dealing with multiple responses, so while you can make it work, it'll be more overhead than dealing with the operation directly.